# How to kill a CMD in Windows knowing only the Title?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, java

The first bat performs the restart of the second bat. I currently use taskkill but it kills all Java processes. I, on the other hand, should only restart START.BAT, which has "MyApplication1" as its title. Is it possible to do that?

RESTART.BAT

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe /T
sleep 1
call "C:\Start.bat"
exit
```

START.BAT

```
title MyApplication1
cd "C:\"
jre1.8\bin\java -jar ./app.jar
exit
```

Comment: Try to invoke java with `start "MyApplication1" C:\jre1.8\bin\java -jar C:\app.jar`. Do you really have a program on C:\ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/FI` Option of the [`taskkill`](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) command to kill the process/es with a specific process tittle.

But ***MyApplication1*** in your example isn't the *title* of the java.exe process, but the title of the bat process (long gone)...

Maybe try to check with `tasklist /V` to see if your process (your specific Java app) has some unique process title.

Comment: if the application is started as a CMD, it cannot be considered as a Service. Right? To start it as a Service I should use like Nssm, right?

Comment: @Koba "started as a cmd" is not a thing, you can start anything from cmd, and the thing you start might automatically start a service as well.